# Tooltip information at DoDragDrop() in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, tooltip

while writing DoDragDrop(), a tooltip message informing that

> **(The documentation is still being
>   constructed. Please try again in a few
>   seconds.)**

**Image**

[image]

**What did it means?**

Comment: In my experience, by the time I see that message, the documentation cache is ready. Just back over the ( and try again. Probably ought to be filed as a bug in VS.

Comment: Did you try again in a few seconds? Or do you repeatedly get that message, even after waiting for a long time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the documentation cache (the cache that is accessed to display tooltip information about members) is still being constructed.  If you try again after a few seconds, you should be able to see the documentation for the method.